# TensorFlow: function reduce_sum input

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am learning TensorFlow from the example at: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/2_BasicModels/linear_regression.ipynb

I have a question in the code below:

```
X = tf.placeholder("float")
Y = tf.placeholder("float")

# Set model weights
W = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias")
In [6]:
# Construct a linear model
pred = tf.add(tf.mul(X, W), b)
In [7]:
# Mean squared error
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
```

The input of tf.reduce_sum is tf.pow(pred-Y, 2)) which seems to be a scalar (or am I wrong?) Then I am wondering why we want to do reduce_sum on a scalar? What did I miss here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tensor `pred` has a **statically** unknown shape, but—due to the [broadcasting semantics](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) of [`tf.add()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/arithmetic_operators#add) and [`tf.mul()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/arithmetic_operators#multiply)—it will have the same **dynamic** shape as the value fed to placeholder `X` (which also has a statically unknown shape).

In the tutorial, when the model is being trained, `X` is fed with scalar values, and so `pred` will be a scalar (and the [`tf.reduce_sum()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/reduction#reduce_sum) will have no effect):

```
# Fit all training data
for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    for (x, y) in zip(train_X, train_Y):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
```

When generating the log message, `X` is fed with a vector (containing all of the training examples), so `pred` will also be a vector of the same length, and `tf.reduce_sum()` will aggregate the cost down to a scalar:

```
    #Display logs per epoch step
    if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
        c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y:train_Y})
```

This example is a little strange, because we typically train TensorFlow models with a [mini-batch](http://sebastianruder.com/optimizing-gradient-descent/index.html#minibatchgradientdescent) of examples, but it demonstrates the usefulness of allowing a [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/placeholders#placeholder) to have a statically undefined shape.

Comment: I read the code again. If the placeholder X is an 1-D array. Why couldn't pred = tf.add(tf.mul(X, W), b) be a 1-D array based on the Numpy broadcast rule? I mean applying the broadcast rule on both the mul and add operations? Thanks!

Comment: If `X` is a 1-D array, then `pred` *will* be a 1-D array (as in the logging case above). However, in the training case when `X` is a scalar, since `W` and `b` are also scalars, `pred` will be a scalar (because the broadcasting rule applied to two scalars is a scalar0.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite new to Tensorflow too, but it looks like you're right. At the moment the training only runs one sample at a time, so the reduce_sum call would effectively be useless.

Try dropping the call to reduce_sum and replacing it with this:

```
cost = tf.pow(pred-Y, 2)/(2*n_samples)
```

It should still function the same way, but break if you try training on batches rather than single samples.